# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer when setting proxy version (using an int) in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, stack-trace

I try to set a socks proxy for chromedriver in Selenium. The code is very basic:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/opt/local/bin/chromedriver"); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setSocksProxy("127.0.0.1:9050");
proxy.setSocksVersion(5);
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

When executing this it crashes

```
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
```

**at myClass.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:32)**

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')**

```
    at org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.<init>(Proxy.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake$Result.lambda$static$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:151)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake$Result.<init>(ProtocolHandshake.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$successHandler$1(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    ... 6 more
```

Line 32 is `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

I am very confused. I tried explicity creating an integer out of `5`, but the result was the same.

When I read the stacktrace it feels like Selenium itself converts my int to a long somewhere along the way!?!? setSocksVersion takes an int so why is it suddenly a long?

1. How to set a socks5-proxy in Selenium? Is the way I am doing it right?
2. Why is *5* suddenly converted to a *long* and what to do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a known bug

try

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--proxy-server=socks5://" + host + ":" + port);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

taken from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5299